# jquery after appendTo cannot focus on input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, focus, appendto

After appending input box to other element, it would not let to click in the box (the focus goes away instantly). Why would this happen? Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/skunksts/HrJ6A/)

HTML

```
<div id="placeHolder" onclick="appendSearch()">placeHolder</div>
<input id='box' type='text'></input>
```

JS

```
function appendSearch(){
    $("#box").appendTo($("#placeHolder"))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appendTo method is what is causing the input to lose focus, as the input is now in the div, and it is calling the function on click. The following code will account for that.

```
function appendSearch(){
    if ($("#placeHolder input").length == 0) {
        $("#box").appendTo($("#placeHolder"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put focus directly in your text box use `.focus()` :

```
$("#box").appendTo($("#placeHolder")).focus();
```

I updated your **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HrJ6A/1/)**

Comment: Yes, i figured it out, however the question is why you cannot focus with mouse click - it just refuses to accept the click...